# Python multithreading : opencv - serial communication

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, pyserial

I want to build a GUI with Tkinter that will show a camera output and analog data from serial port at the same time.Here is my code :

```
width, height = 400, 300
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("GUI")
root.geometry("800x600+100+100")
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = tk.Label()
lmain.pack(padx=100, pady=100)
frameLabel = tk.Frame()
text = tk.Text(frameLabel, wrap='word', font='TimesNewRoman 15', relief='flat')
frameLabel.pack()
text.pack()

def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)


def serialData():
    data = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
    while (True):
        if (data.inWaiting() > 0):
            ardu_data = data.readline()
            text.delete(1.0, 'end')
            text.insert('end', ardu_data)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=show_frame())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=serialData())

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()


root.mainloop()
```

The code can't perform two operations at the same time.Please someone help me with the code.Thanks.

Comment: Why do you try to join the threads before your main loop?

Comment: You also seem to use the GUI objects from multiple threads -- that's [unlikely to work correctly](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm). [\[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=tkinter%20thread)

Comment: I tried to join threads after main loop but it didn't work too. @DanMašek

Comment: Well, yes, but the reason why it didn't work weren't those joins. The order you show in this question is wrong -- `root.mainloop()` is what "makes the GUI work", so you want your threads to be alive as long as that's running (i.e. you want to join them after the main loop ends, or just around that time). Further issue is that `t2.join()` will [block forever](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects), since you're trying to join a thread that's stuck in an infinite loop. `t1.join()` is OK, since that thread is useless anyway -- runs the function once and dies.

Comment: That said, there are many issues with that code. Some things I'd recommend: 1) Separate responsibilities more and use Queues to feed data to your GUI (like in the link in my second comment). 2) Use objects for the implementation of the two worker threads, and provide means to stop the thread properly. 3) Initialize `VideoCapture` in the worker thread (you may run into issues going cross threads depending on platform/backend). 4) Add timestamps to both the image stream and the serial data stream, so you can correlate the two together.

Comment: I used your advices and I've managed to work it out ,thank you so much @DanMašek